# how to compute marginal effect at representative values for a logit model in python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I searched through internet and found no solution in python.
How to do similar stata command in python like

```
margins, at(age=(30(1)35))
```

I browsed the statsmodels doc and found no readily available solution.

Comment: How does `margins, at(age=(30(1)35))` set other covariates? Are those set to their mean values?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i just figured this out myself. I think it is to set to their means.